# Spring Security Role based access restriction

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security. As per my understanding from the tutorials, we will configure the user roles in the antMatcher.

My question is, if `admin` is logged in, is it identifies the URL from the context like `/admin` and allows the permission? If it is so, I have to write individual role based method for `/admin/operation` and `/user/operation`. But, how can I restrict the user other than context level implementation.

In other words, I should have only one method with `/operation` within the operation, I should identify the user role and have to perform role based operation.

How this could be done?

Please help...

Answer (score -1):

You only need to define list of resource URL using antMatchers() method which need authentication. The user having certain role will be able to access the resource no need to do for rest roles. Below I have defined two configurations for both HTTP Basic and Form Based Authentication.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        public static final String REALM_NAME = "startwithjava.com";
        @Configuration
        @Order(1)
        public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            @Autowired
            LoggingAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

            @Autowired
            AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

            @Autowired
            AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

            @Autowired
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/",
                                "/js/**",
                                "/css/**",
                                "/img/**",
                                "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .logout()
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
                daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
                daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
                auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
            }
        }
        @Configuration
        @Order(2)
        public static class ApiTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
            @Autowired
            AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .csrf()
                           .disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/**")
                        .hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .and()
                        .httpBasic()
                            .realmName(REALM_NAME)
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(new ApiAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            }
            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
                daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
                auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
            }

        }

    }
```